# Ubuntu CLI, replace a long filepath/filename with a shortcut

Tags: command-line, directory, shortcuts, paths, filename

I have a **long path** to some of my files and I **don't want to type** and/or **use the <kbd>Tab</kbd>-key as much** when using it with commands in the Terminal.
So I want to add "shortcuts" to some of them (both files and directories), e.g.

> replace
> `ls folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/`
>
> with something like
> `ls folder1234`

and

> replace
> `cat folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/my_super_very_long_amazing_filename.txt`
>
> with something like
> `cat long_path_and_filename.txt` (but obviously shorter :))
>
> or if it's not possible, then with two "replace commands" like
> `cat folder1234/short_filename`

Are any of the above possible?
Can you use the `ln` command or maybe the `alias` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Something fulfilling what you believe would work best**

One way to create "shortcuts" for pathnames would be to define environment variables:

```
export folder1234='folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4'
export short_filename='my_super_very_long_amazing_filename.txt'
```

This way, you could reduce your typing to

```
ls $folder1234
cat $folder1234/$short_filename
```

While that sounds like a magnificent idea, nobody appears to do that. It indeed requires you to set up and maintain static definitions, *and* remember all of these artifacts. These will work the period you work on a project, but will be largely obsolete once you move to a different project.

**The better workflow using standard tools**

The better way to avoid long path names, is to turn into a habbit of changing to the directory where you need to do your work. This way, it takes a single

```
cd folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/
```

(where you use autocompletion and tab) to bring you there. Next day, you will get there more quickly: instead of attempting the command again, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>: this starts a reverse search through your history. Type `folder4`  and you will quickly see your `cd` command again. Select it and execute it. Done.

Once inside that folder, typing the long filename is a no-brainer using the tab autocompletion.

**On steroids**

Install **[fuzzy finder](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)**. `sudo apt install fzf`

At the empty prompt, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. Fuzzy finder will pop up. Type `folder4`: you will see the full folder name, select it, hit enter and you are there.

Type `cat`  then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. `my_super_very` may already reveal your file only. Hit enter to add the full path to the command line.

Alternative to the above: type `**` then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to trigger fussy finder.

Answer (score 0):

Why not alias them?

In *buntu .bashrc is located in `/home`. I believe .bashrc looks for a file named .bash_aliases for your own custom aliases.

so for you to (in terminal) do:

```
nano .bash_aliases
```

Then you can add your custom aliases to the file(for example):

```
alias ls_mine='ls /Documents && ls /Downloads | cat'
```

Then save and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

Then run:

```
source .bashrc
```

And try your alias.

You can always edit your aliases anytime by:

```
nano .bash_aliases
```

Remember to save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> then run:

```
source .bashrc
```